# Socket.io client switching to xhr-polling with error

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm running a Chat-server with Nodejs and Socket.io, in some browsers everything is working fine and using the native websockets.

But in some cases it's using **xhr-polling** with problem.

Firebug output :

```
GET http://{domain}:8080/socket.io/1/?t={time}
GET http://{domain}:8080/socket.io/1/xhr-polling/X_mBol8OqjbULLXozLc?t={time} 200 OK 2m
Error: The connection to ws://{domain}:8080/socket.io/1/websocket/dsEWQdsaDWQEcHTR was interrupted while the page was loading
...yep.name="flashsocket",c.prototype.open=function(){var a=this, c=arguments; return...
GET http://{domain}:8080/socket.io/1/xhr-polling/X_mBol8OqjbULLXozLc?t={time} 200 OK 20s
GET http://{domain}:8080/socket.io/1/xhr-polling/X_mBol8OqjbULLXozLc?t={time} 200 OK 20s
```

Firebug Screenshot : http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=23r5pvb&s=5

Client Information :

- No anti-virus and proxy application is running
- Client is using modern bowser
- I'm using this pieces of code for configuring socket.io

socket.io configure:

```
io.configure(function(){
    io.enable('browser client minification');
    io.enable('browser client etag');
    io.enable('browser client gzip');
    io.set('transports', [
        'websocket'
        , 'flashsocket'
        , 'htmlfile'
        , 'xhr-polling'
        , 'jsonp-polling'
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Does your router have DynamicNAT/LRU or NAT Filtering enabled in the router settings page?

Comment: @PubNub How can I check router settings in CentOS? iptables?

Comment: May not be a settings param as there are general hardware limits that you must be aware.

Answer (score 0):

> **The connection to ws**://{domain}:8080/socket.io/1/websocket/dsEWQdsaDWQEcHTR **was interrupted** while the page was loading

This holds the key to the problem, I think its failing back to xhr-polling since there is an error connecting via ws.